# Why does an element with { flex: 1; width: 0; } still have width?

Tags: html, facebook, css, flexbox

Facebook uses this CSS:

```
{flex: 1;  width: 0;}
```

but the div still has width.

[image: Image here]

Comment: This seems to be the proper answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7985973/6859915

Answer (score 12):

You're asking about two different properties and functions.

`flex: 1` is equivalent to `flex: 1 1 0`, both of which are shorthand equivalents of:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

When you add `width: 0`, it's actually redundant and unnecessary in a row-direction container, like the one in the question.

`flex-basis: 0` = `width: 0` in this case.

If this `flex-basis` / `width` rule were by itself, then you would have your expected behavior: The element would have 0 width.

However, these properties only set the *initial main size* of a flex item, before free space is distributed by other flex properties.

With `flex-grow: 1`, the item will consume all available space on the line *after having factored in `flex-basis` / `width`*.

More information:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)
- [7.1. The `flex` Shorthand](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property)
- [7.1.1. Basic Values of `flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)

Comment: According to the spec it might be redundant, but at least in chromium, you sometimes have to set `width:0` even when using `flex-basis:0`. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=464210

Comment: @HåkenLid, correct. I cover this issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276), under the section "Browser Bugs" in my answer.