# Difference between flex-grow = 1, width: auto and just width: 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox, off-canvas-menu

Given this HTML:

```
<nav id="drawer" class="dark_blue">
  <h2>Off Canvas</h2>
  <p>Click outside the drawer to close</p>
</nav>

<main class="light_blue">
  <a id="menu">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M2 6h20v3H2zm0 5h20v3H2zm0 5h20v3H2z"/>
    </svg>
  </a>
  <p>Click on the menu icon to open the drawer</p>
</main>
```

And these CSS properties (they're really inside a media query)

```
body {
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
 }

 main {
     width: auto;
     /* Flex-grow streches the main content to fill all available space.*/
     flex-grow: 1;
 }
```

Couldn't I just use

```
main {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Instead of

```
main {
    width: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Visually, they have the same effect.

Here, [a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jorgeas80/hy9L9gwc/1/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39960047/3597276

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39884226/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, `width:auto` makes the element occupy all available space. At a basic level, if some space is occupied, it occupies the rest. `width: 100%` on the other hand means that the element will occupy its entire parent.

Flex grow, however, says how much space an element occupies. If there are two child elements inside a parent, and you give one of them a `flex-grow: 2` it will occupy twice as much space as the other